# Dynamic data from this website(nseindia.com) not importing in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

Website Link : https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=TCS&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=+&fromDate=13-12-2019&toDate=18-12-2019&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE', headers=headers)

df = pd.read_html(r.text)

print(df)
```

I have tried code this but its giving me this error **ValueError: No tables found**

Comment: If check `print(r.text)` it return `Access denied`

Comment: Can you specify what data do you want to scrape?

Comment: **Enter symbol:** TCS
**Select series:** EQ
**Select a Time Period:** 13-12-2019 to18-12-2019
 After filling these it is returning a table..this table i am trying to scrape @ans2human

Comment: @jezrael Is there any way to scrape that table??